# Deploy laravel 5.4 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.4, apache2.4

I'm developing a new laravel application, it works fine, when I deployed it to windows server (apache as web server).

There is some issues here:

1. virtual hosts not working
2. it shows homepage correctly, but if I visit any other pages it shows the following error:

   Not Found

   The requested URL /portal/public/register was not found on this server.

php is configured normally (which makes laravel works fine). I did the following configurations to deploy it.

in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\portal\www\portal\public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerAdmin portal.dev
    #ServerName portal.dev
    #ServerAlias www.portal.dev
    <Directory "E:\portal\www\portal\public">
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_reweite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If virtual hosts arent working, have you checked your apache configuration? This question seems more fitted to the `apache` category and not doesnt seem like a Laravel issue.

Comment: what kind of configurations should I check??

Comment: You should check that you have the `mod_vohsts` module enabled if you are using virtual hosts. you should also check you have the `mod_rewrite` module enabled in your apache configuration.

Comment: the second point `Not Found` is solved, but the first one stills

Comment: when I go to browser to (portal.dev) it routes me to the root folder (where I store all my projects). my project open when I visit `portal.dev/portal/public` how can I convert it to read the `portal.dev` directly?

Comment: You should look at your vhost configuration. Check the module is enabled firstly.

Comment: I'm sure it is enabled

Comment: Without you showing any configuration or logs it is impossible to pinpoint the issue